# (Android) ListView: Load 5 items at a time, when scroll down

Tags: android

So I made an sliding tabs app that loads json into a listview. My question is how would I implement something that would only load 5 listview items in the beginning and would load another 5 when you scroll down? (Instead of loading all of the listview items in the beginning)

I have search the web and I can't really understand how to do this. Any suggestions or ideas will be appreciated.

This is some of my code. These classes is where I think the code would go: I used SlidingTabLayout & strip from the android developer site.

**CustomListAdapter code:**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Tanga> tangasItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Tanga> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.tangasItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tangasItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return tangasItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Tanga m = tangasItems.get(position);

    // title
    name.setText(m.getName());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
private static final String url = "website.json";
private List<Tanga> tangaList = new ArrayList<Tanga>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), tangaList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Tanga movie = new Tanga();

                            //name
                            String name = obj.getString("name");
                            movie.setName(name);


                            // adding movie to movies array
                            tangaList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Error: ");

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs, container, false);

    return v;
}
}
```

**Tanga Code: (model)**

```
public class Tanga {
private String name;

public Tanga() {
}

public Tanga(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: Use view holder pattern?

Comment: put listview inside scrollview so that with scrollview onscroll listener you will get items count ,so after that for every time when you scrolls take that count when it reaches 5, hit webservice for remaining  5 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could handle this, the simplest way would be to create another `ArrayList` of type `Tanga`, let's suppose it's name is `tangaList2`. What you have to do is in your for loop write this code.

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Tanga movie = new Tanga();

                        //name
                        String name = obj.getString("name");
                        movie.setName(name);


                        // adding movie to movies array
                        if(i < 5) {
                        tangaList.add(movie);
                        }
                        else { 
                        tangaList2.add(movie);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Now after this you should also implement the onScrollListener in your Fragment:

```
     listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if ((++firstVisibleItem) + visibleItemCount > totalItemCount)     {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5  && tangaList2.size() > 0; i++){
         tangaList.add(tangaList2.get(0));
         tangaList2.remove(0);
        }
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'll try it out. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind, where do i add the listView.setOnScrollListener?

Comment: Add it just before this line: JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(......)

Comment: Hm, it tells me that Cant resolve symbol OnScrollListener, It suggest I change to AbsListView.OnScrollListener. But when I try it changes the method to this:      public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
                
            }

Comment: Hello again, sorry to ask again but it gives me  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0.... at com.example.mariogp18.tanga.Tab1$1.onScroll(Tab1.java:66)
11

Comment: It worked but when I scrolled down it crashed. "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4". Also, I am grateful for your help.

Comment: . "at com.example.mariogp18.tanga.Tab1$1.onScroll(Tab1.java:66)" which is tangalist.add(tangalist2.get(i)

Comment: Hey man it still crashed: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4...at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)...at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)...at com.example.mariogp18.tanga.Tab1$1.onScroll(Tab1.java:66).....Same error. Thank you for your help but if you want to stop it's okay.

Comment: I know why it crashed, i have fixed it. It will work now.

Comment: I get a new error with the changes you made: 11-08 22:21:45.384 14952-14952/com.example.mariogp18.tanga E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131492934, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.mariogp18.tanga.CustomListAdapter)]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94565/discussion-between-eric247-and-beginnerhelp).